# The use of input type in EditText

Tags: android

Even if I set the input type to `numberdecimal` or number, I have to cast the number to get the number. Then what is the use of `input type` in `EditText` views.

e.g.

```
int a = Integer.valueOf(editText.getText().toString());
```

One more thing, why do I need to use `toString()` with almost every views to get Text? In java, we could just `getText` anything from controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to parse Text to Integer because it doesn't return int. It returns Editable formatted by input type. So if you set input type to numbers you get Editable which contains only numbers. 
And you have to add toString() because EditText return Editables not Strings.

Comment: Should I use Integer.ParseInt or ValueOF for calculations

Comment: long weight,weight=Long.valueOf(etWeight.getText().toString()); is giving NumberFormatException...WHY ? as far as I know that Integer.parseInt return Integer object but I want a primitive type int.

Comment: You CAN use Integer.parseInt:  int bla = Integer.parseInt(string); It works. As well as Long.parseLong()

Comment: The valueOf() returns Long or Integer, not primitive type.

Comment: Looking in AndroidDevelopers references http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29 and http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: You can see here... parseInt returns int and valueOf returns Integer

Comment: yes U r right, thats what I meant (though I forgot which is which) but I knew there's a difference in primitive and object type. Thanx bro.

Comment: 1 more thing, is there any float type for calculation, or shud I use long for decimal value?  and int age=Integer.parseInt(etAge.getText().toString()); is saying "unable to parse as interger

Comment: In java you have short, int, long, float and double values.

Comment: if it is age than use int age = Integer.parseInt(etAge...)

Comment: Use double values double d = Double.parseDouble(string);

Comment: why on earth is still showing error for- double weight=Double.parseDouble(etWeight.getText().toString());

Comment: Upppss I got it now, I didnt put value into another EditText of input type number.....sigh....Thanx bro

Answer (score 0):

InputType is used for various purposes. For example, in a password field, it can hide the characters.

Here's the official description of every single property it can take:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType

As for the second part of your question, EditText.getText() returns [Editable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html)

This defines a common interface for all text whose content and markup can be changed (as opposed to immutable text like Strings).

So you need to use toString() to get a string out of it.